# "Scampi" in American English?

Tags: word-usage

Is *scampi* the common name used for the kind of shrimp in the picture in American English? Or is there an alternative common name for it? I ask because some Americans don't really know the word when I mention it to them.

[image]

Comment: Check out [Wikipedia on shrimp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrimp#Commercial_and_culinary_definition) or a [definition of scampi](http://www.answers.com/topic/scampi). I have not heard "scampi" alone, but rather "shrimp scampi," in the US to refer to shrimp prepared a certain way, regardless of what kind of shrimp.

Comment: Dang! In the UK that would be "monster ginormous scampi"!

Comment: Them things have *claws*. Them things ain't shrimp. But they do look yummy.

Comment: Them is crawdads.

Comment: @Malvolio: them ain't crawdads. Crawdads are freshwater critters, and those guys live in the Mediterranean and the Atlantic near Europe. We don't have them in the U.S., which is why Americans don't know the name for them.

Comment: @PeterShor -- They look like crawdads to me, but if you are findin' 'em in salt water, I guess they ain't.  My next guess'd be *Nephrops norvegicus*, or somethin'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That species (the Norwegian lobster) is known as either *scampi* (always in the plural in English for some reason) or *langoustine*, if the method of preparation is French. In North American usage, *scampi* is also often used for prawn prepared according to Italian recipes (the term is also somewhat interchangeable in Italy).

The word isn't unknown, but the little lobsters (they're not shrimp) are nearly so; shrimp, prawn, various larger species of lobster (American lobster served whole, or spiny lobster served as "lobster tails"), and crayfish (freshwater lobster) are much more common in North America -- we have substantial fisheries for all of them here. "Foodies" will know what *scampi* are, but most people will either not know the word or associate it with the shrimp dish at the local Italian restaurant.

Answer (score 5):

*Scampi* is the name of *Nephrops norvegicus*. In Britain, the fish labelling regulations state that these four names can be used for *Nephrops norvegicus*: Scampi, Dublin Bay prawns, Langoustine, and Norway lobster.

In America, the word *scampi* was first used as a name for the *dish* Scampi fritti, or deep-fried shrimp, since they didn’t have *Nephrops norvegicus* in the States.

The word *scampi* is, to conclude, the name of a certain species (animal)— *not* the name of a shrimp (Tiger prawns, King prawns or Giant prawns, cultured prawns). And as such, it has nothing to do with cultured prawns; they are a quite different species.