# What are set of words word like "crocodiles" and "alligators", and "turtle" and "tortoise" called?

Tags: nouns

There are times when various words can both be used to describe one particular kind of animal. The animal one word specifies is a bit different from the other(s), but in most cases there's plenty of overlap and few know the little things about them that differentiates them.

1. > *crocodile* and *alligator*
2. > *turtle* and *tortoise*
3. > *shrimp*/*prawn* and *lobster*
4. > *crab*, *lobster*, and *crayfish*

EDIT: I know, the examples are a bit confusing. I wrote this in a hurry, thinking that I'll edit it later on (which I *have* done). The species/catagory these words fall into is the same.

Comment: Does 'synonym' work? Or do you think there's a word specifically for animals?

Comment: 'Synonym' is incorrect. 'Confusibles' for words often confused, and 'classmates' for 'words connected at a fairly obvious level' [think looser thesaurus groupings] (knives/forks/spoons; alligator/crocodile/gharial/caiman ...) are sometimes used.

Comment: (3) and (4) are all *shellfish*, if you wish to avoid mistakes ;o)

Comment: Well, shrimp and prawn can be called regional variations of English. Whereas the others are confusing species. crab, lobster and crayfish are confused?? Dunno.....who is confusing these terms? Your question hinges on two different issues.....

Comment: There isn't any special word; things are too various and fall into too many different categories for such a word. They're just words that refer to similar things, and that's all.

Comment: I was going to suggest "reptiles" and "arthropods" but then saw what you meant. You should realise that prawns and lobsters are not the same crustaceans, likewise turtles and tortoises, along with alligators and crocodiles are separate species. I suppose "confusables" might fit

Answer (score 3):

These are **prototypes** in the language of taxonomy.

> In many sciences, from pathology to taxonomy, prototype refers to a disease, species, etc. which sets a good example for the whole category.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype

Another term is *archetype*, but it tends to be a more formal designation, something like a prototype with credentials.

They are not, as has been pointed out, *synonyms*, nor are they *misnomers*.

A more general idea is *pars pro toto*, where a part is used to refer to the whole. A *mereism* is a list of parts intended to substitute for the whole. Thus the sets are mereisms for the clades that contain them. Unfortunately, [*mereism*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/merism) has a particular meaning in biology, and would be confusing if used this way here.

Comment: pars prot toto is commonly called synecdoche. [why is that word underlined in red here??] Are these just confusing species, to the layperson?

Comment: I'm taking it as people who don't know enough about them to be confused. Most people have a strong local bias based on what they see every day, even if they are considered oddities elsewhere. @bof Thanks fixing that now.

Comment: Never mind. I hesitate to say anything because I will be sent to chat. :) But I think her question mixes apples and oranges in a basic way: similar species, different species and regional variations in English, all lumped together.

Comment: @Lambie agreed.

Answer (score 2):

### umbrella term (or) blanket term

Is I think what the OP is after. A word that covers many different, but closely related things. For example, an American might refer to a crocodile as an alligator because they might be more familiar with that species of semiaquatic reptile. Someone from the southern states of the US might call Norwegian lobsters, langoustine, scampi, or prawns as *crayfish* ([source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241766/how-did-lobster-mean-two-different-species/242815#242815)) because they seem to belong to the same genus. It's quicker to say, and remember

Twenty years ago, I remember hearing children call tortoises, turtles because of the popular 1980s cartoon series, *Ninja Turtles*.

> An **umbrella term** is a word or phrase that covers a wide range of concepts belonging to a common category. For example, cryptology is an umbrella term that encompasses cryptography and cryptanalysis, among other fields.
>
> A **blanket term** is a closely related word or phrase that is used to describe multiple groups of related things.
>
> - The degree of relation may vary or have a minimal relationship, but blanket terms often trade specificity for ease of use.
> - In other words, a blanket term, by itself, gives little detail about the things that it describes or the relationships between them, **but it is easy to say and remember.**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_term)